# How to get process id by its service name with a script to variable

Tags: powershell, windows-7, process, tasklist

I have service named `WinDefend` and it runs on process `svchost.exe`
There other many `svchost.exe` processes and I need to find a way to get its ID.
when I run `tasklist /svc` I can see:
[image]

I am not sure how can I get it.
I found this command but when I tried the `select "PID"` it gave me empty column.
[image]

I need to get the PID of the process to variable.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`tasklist` is just returning text, not actual objects that have properties you can access. You can use WMI to get this information instead:

```
$id = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'WinDefend'" | 
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId

$process = Get-Process -Id $id
```

**Update for PowerShell Core**

In version 6, Windows PowerShell started towards cross platform support with PowerShell Core based on .NET Core. This led to many changes in cmdlets that were Windows-centric and some being left out completely. WMI is a Windows only technology, so its cmdlets (e.g. Get-WmiObject) were not ported over. However, its features are available via CIM cmdlets (e.g. Get-CimInstance) here is a version that will work on PowerShell 6+:

```
$id = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'WinDefend'" | 
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId

$process = Get-Process -Id $id
```

Comment: I am sorry for the very dumb question but where do i execute this?

Comment: @RaulChiarella In powershell? :) I'm not sure quite what you mean, but with powershell core being the standard now I've made an update that should work with that version.

Answer (score 8):

```
$p=Tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq windefend" /fo csv | convertfrom-csv
$p.PID
```

Answer (score 3):

Annoying as this is, it requires you to set a unique title for your script if you want the pid for the current process.  Then search for that unique title within the list of processes.  Thankfully, the Title command allows you to do just that. Also see MagicAndi's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342292/identify-the-pid-of-a-executing-batch-file-in-powershell/1342376#1342376)...

Here is my batch file solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
:SetVars
    SET _Thread=%1
    title=ExecBatch_%_Thread%
    Set /A "_iPID=0"
:Main
    CALL :getPID _iPID %_Thread%
    ...
EXIT /b

::----------------
::---- GetPID ---- 
::----------------
:getPID 
    setlocal   
        set _getPIDcmd=tasklist /v /fo csv 
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%i in ('%_getPIDcmd% ^| findstr /i "ExecBatch_%2"') do (
            echo %%~i
            set _pid=%%~i
        )
    endlocal & Set %~1=%_pid%
exit /b
```

BTW, I've had the 'pleasure' of doing this time and time again over the years, via API, or batch, or ps.  Pick your poison - on a Windows platform it's all the same.

I found an even better way via powershell: $pid returns the current process' process id.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question by a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Enter servicename. (instead of 'netman')
$service = Get-CimInstance -class win32_service | Where-Object name -eq 'netman' | select name, processid
$process = Get-Process | Where-Object ID -EQ $service.processid
Clear-Host
Write-Host '********* ServiceName, PID and ProcessName ******'
Write-Host 'ServiceName:' $service.name 
Write-Host 'ID:' $process.Id 
Write-Host 'ProcessName:' $process.Name
```

Thanks,

Comment: While this answer may solve the question it would be much more useful if you explained how it works

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to get a process PID:

```
$serviceName = 'svchost.exe'
$pidArgumentPlacement = 1

# Call for the verbose version of tasklist and filter it for the line with your service's name. 
$serviceAsCSVString = tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i $serviceName

# Remove the quotes from the CSV string
$serviceCSVStringWithoutQuotes = $serviceAsCSVString -replace '["]'
# Turn the string into an array by cutting at the comma
$serviceAsArray = $serviceCSVStringWithoutQuotes -split ","
# Get the pid from the array
$servicePID = $serviceAsArray[$pidArgumentPlacement]
```

Or you can sum it up to:

```
$servicePID = $($($(tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i $serviceName) -replace '["]') -split ",")[$pidArgumentPlacement]
```

**Note:** This will grab the first service that matches your `$serviceName`, if you run a service that runs several instances of itself *(e.x. slack)* you'll only get the first pid. `tasklist /v /fi "IMAGENAME eq slack.exe" /fo csv` will return an array with each CSV line being an array entry. You can also filter this with `findstr` to avoid getting the column names.

EDIT:
As WinDefend is a subservice of a program (In this case `svchost.exe`) you may need to swap the verbose flag for `tasklist` to `/svc` like so:

```
$serviceAsCSVString = tasklist /svc /fo csv | findstr /i $serviceName
```

alternatively search for the service's name through a filter:

```
$serviceAsCSVString = tasklist /svc /fi "SERVICES eq $serviceName" /fo csv | findstr /i $serviceName
```

And taking into account that the filter returns a row of column names as well as the line you were looking for:

```
$serviceCSVStringWithoutQuotes = $serviceAsCSVString[1] -replace '["]'
```

Assuming you've changed `$serviceName` to `WinDefend` instead of `svchost.exe`.

Comment: When I run `$servicename = 'WinDefend'
$pidArgumentPlacement = 1

# Call for the verbose version of tasklist and filter it for the line with your service's name. 
$serviceAsCSVString = tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i $serviceName` the `$serviceAsCSVString` is empty.

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo in my script; `$serviceName` was misspelled on the first line. Try it again and make sure the variable names match; powershell is case sensitive.

Comment: It sitll doesn't work and Powershell is not case sensitive.
If you will run `$a = "a"; $A` you will see that it will print the same value.
Did you check this code on your machine ?
Run just:
`$serviceName = 'WinDefend'
$pidArgumentPlacement = 1
tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i $serviceName`
It won't find anything.
The problem is because you are not using the `/svc` switch that displays the service name.
Therefore it doesn't display the `WinDefend` service.
Fix for your code:
Just replace `/v` to `/svc`
Btw `svchost.exe` is not a good example because it is not a service.

Comment: I've updated my Answer, it seems that I was missunderstanding what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Process -Id ((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name -eq 'WinDefend'").ProcessId)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. (gps -id (get-wmiobject -query "select * from win32_service where name='sevicename'").processid).priority class="priority"

Do that command and it will set the specified service even it's in svchost.

Edited: You are only looking for the PID. just do the same command minus the priority setting. I was assuming you are going to use it to set priority. Hehe

Answer (score 0):

While the WMI option is good, I wanted something in a single PS line so I could easily insert it into the rather cludgy scripting toolset of the RMM tool my company uses.

What I came up with was:

```
(tasklist /FI "Services eq WinDefend"/FO LIST | findstr /B "PID:") -replace "[^0-9]" , ''
```

You could take it to the conclusion I did by then wrapping it into a taskkill command:

```
taskkill /f /pid ((tasklist /FI "Services eq WinDefend"/FO LIST | findstr /B "PID:") -replace "[^0-9]" , '')
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this and it works fine. YMMV

```
$ProcessName = "SomeProcessName"

$pidnumber = Get-Process -Name $ProcessName | Select -expand ID
```

Comment: But my case is different. The process name is `svchost.exe` which appears couple of times in the task manager.  Then, you need to find only the one that is related to the service of the WinDefend" and just showing the IDs of all the `svchost.exe` won't solve it

Comment: I'm trying to do this on a service, I can't seem to use the -expand id with get-service.

Comment: @PHenry that's because the service name will not be necessarily the same as the process name. This is a pretty bad answer in response to the question.