# Kill process in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I tried to kill process from PowerShell by `Stop-Service -Name (service name)`. 
Sometimes the process exits properly, but sometimes even though the service gets stopped the background Java process for this app doesn't stop. Is there a solution to stop Java if it hasn't from PowerShell. The problem is that we have to find the right Java process and kill only that as we have other Java processes also running.

Comment: You can use `Stop-Process` to terminate a process. However, we cannot tell you how to identify a particular Java process that we know nothing about.

Comment: If the service starts the background java process, it's the service's responsability to clean it up. You *can* get a list of the child processes by enumerating all processes and look at its parent PID but note that that will only work 99% of the time. Windows does not really have a concept of parent/child processes. It's better to fix the service.

Answer (score 2):

`Stop-Service` doesn't kill a process. It makes a request to the [service control manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-control-manager) (SCM) to ask it to stop a service with a particular name. The SCM will then call into the process hosting the service and ask it to stop.

It's possible that the service won't shut down correctly when asked, and the SCM will timeout the call to stop the service. This tends to lead to the service showing as stopped in the SCM but still running in the background, which is what you are seeing.

If you want to explicitly kill the process hosting the service then you'll need to find a way to map the service name to a process id. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331183/how-to-get-process-id-by-its-service-name-with-a-script-to-variable) may help you.

Comment: I interpreted the question different but perhaps you are right and OP is just looking to kill the service process, not child processes spawned by the service.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - It's not quite clear what the question is, so I had a guess based on my experience with troublesome services!