# How can know the usage of CPU of a windows service in an interval of time with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-services, cpu-usage

I am a beginner with PowerShell, How can know the usage of CPU of a windows service in an interval of time (for example for one hour) with PowerShell? 
Something like this:

```
Get-Service | Get-counter
```

Thank so much

Comment: Resmon.exe/perfmon.exe perhaps a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CPU usage you need to use the get-process commandlet and then map the process name with the corresponding service.

Here is one of the past discussion thread where the get-process is discussed

[Listing processes by CPU usage percentage in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943928/listing-processes-by-cpu-usage-percentage-in-powershell)

**Sample code here**

```
$Details = @()
$AllRunningServices = Get-CimInstance -class win32_service | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'}  | Select-Object ProcessId , Name 

foreach($procid in $AllRunningServices)
{
$Details += Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $procid.ProcessId} | Select-Object ProcessName, Id, CPU , @{Name = "serviceName" ; Expression={$procid.Name}}

}

$Details |Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending | ft
```

Comment: How can I map the process name with the corresponding service? thank so much!

Comment: Each service will spawn its process. For eaxample SQL Server service will spawn sqlservr.exe process. Pick the process names PID and match with the appropriate service. Like how it is mentioned here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331183/how-to-get-process-id-by-its-service-name-with-a-script-to-variable

Comment: Added a sample code in my answer which you can use to develop further.