# Get service name by process id which is run by this service on windows using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there any way to retrieve service name by process which is run by this service. There are ways to get service by name like:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match $service_name}
```

or to get Id of a process which is run by service like in this answer:
[How to get process id by its service name with a script to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331183/how-to-get-process-id-by-its-service-name-with-a-script-to-variable)
But in my particular case I need revert way, to go from the bottom to parent service which runs the process. Lets say I would have process id and basing on this information I would like to retrieve service name which run this process. Thanks for all ideas in advance.

Comment: Not sure about you requirement but isn't that a simple `gwmi -Class Win32_Service | where ProcessId -gt 10`

Comment: @Lieven Keersmaekers Did not think about that, thx it works! this is what I needed :)

Comment: np, been there. You would not believe the amount of code I've created that could have been solved with a oneliner. I assume we tend to overengineer :)