# How to determine the port on which a Windows service is listening?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, windows-services

I have running a Windows service called `my-service`. The only input that I know is the **service name**.

I can get the **process identifier** by using the **service name**:

```
$id = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "name='my-service'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProcessId
```

To get a list of Listening ports, I can use `netstat`, but all my custom services have `PID` **4** which is not equal to the service **process identifier** of `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet.

[image: netstat.exe -ano]

The goal is to get the port on which the service is listening by using PowerShell or CMD based on the **service name** or the **process identifier** and NOT by the **image name**.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Get-NetTCPConnection` to identify sockets on which the given process is currently listening:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -OwningProcess $id -State Listen
```

Comment: The ```OwningProcess ID``` it's different than ```Process ID``` of the service.

Comment: @OrestGulman I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The ```OwningProcess ID``` in my case id is ```4``` with ```ProcessName``` = ```System``` while in the same time the ```ProcessId``` is ```1272```

Comment: @OrestGulman That means the service isn't using the port directly but has registered with an OS component to listen on its behalf - this happens when you register path prefixes with the HTTP driver in Windows for example - your program tells Windows "I'd like to respond to requests for `/some/path`", and the Kernel forwards the traffic to the program. You can find registered prefixes with `netsh http show urlacl` or by [interfacing with `Httpapi.dll`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/http/nf-http-httpqueryserviceconfiguration), but they'll be tied to an account, not a PID

Answer (score 0):

Might you could combine [Get-NetTcpConnection -OwningProcess XXXX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=windowsserver2019-ps#example-4--get-owning-process) with [How to get process id by its service name with a script to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331183/how-to-get-process-id-by-its-service-name-with-a-script-to-variable)?

Answer (score 0):

As you have included the [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) tag, here's an idea you could try, in the cmd.exe, i.e. Windows Command Prompt:

```sh
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=," %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /SVC /Fi "Services Eq my-service" /Fo CSV /NH 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=: " %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\netstat.exe -ano ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "[^0123456789]%~G$" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "["') Do @Echo %H
```

Just change `my-service` to your 'real' service name.